# Get hard disk serial number from local disk in batch

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, batch-file

I need to get the model and serial number of the disk on which windows is installed (local disk C). This way I can get the one from all disks, but how can I get the one from the local disk only?

```
wmic diskdrive get model,serialNumber
```

Comment: I've used `wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk WHERE "BootFromDisk='true'" get model, serialnumber`

Comment: That will check if it is the Boot Partition. If you want to verify if it is the System Partition, use `"IsSystem='TRUE'"` [MSFT_Disk](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/microsoft/windows/storage/msft_disk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command displays the virtual disk information of the computer

```
Get-Disk -Number 0 | % {$_.FriendlyName,$_.SerialNumber}
```

If you want to run it in cmd or batch file

```
powershell.exe -command "Get-Disk -Number 0 | % {$_.FriendlyName,$_.SerialNumber}"
```

Comment: How do you know that the disk is number `0`? That is essentially doing the same thing as the OP was, but by guessing the filter, i.e. `wmic diskdrive where index=0 get model,serialnumber`. The Operating System can be running on any of the installed disks on the system, so are you categorically telling us that the running OS will always reorder/assign itself to Disk #0?

Comment: The first Windows drive is listed as C: and Disk 0 In Disk Management

https://superuser.com/a/668964/1642523

Comment: I believe that is an assumption, I have an old PC somewhere in my graveyard, and I am 100% certain that the system drive is `D:`. Additionally [this image](https://ibb.co/sHcF2G3) disproves that Disk Management assigns it to Disk 0 too!

Comment: You can set the letter when installing the windows system, and regardless of the letter, the disk you are installing the system in is 0

Comment: Check my image again, it contradicts your statement.

Comment: Well, I admit I'm wrong