# Get the serial number of the hard disk who host windows os

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, hard-drive

I'm trying to get the serial number of the hard disk who host windows os in a consistant way through python calling windows cmd from subprocess

So far using :

```
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber,index
```

Which give me back something like :

```
Index  SerialNumber
1      000000001536
0      0025_XXXX_2142_XXXX.
2      000000001536
```

However the first, nor the index 0 is not always the hardrive with the OS...
(as mentionned in the answer in [Get hard disk serial number from local disk in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960445/get-hard-disk-serial-number-from-local-disk-in-batch))

Is there a command to get the hard drive serial number of where is installer the Windows OS ?

Thanks,

Comment: I  wanted to access it with wmic in order to be able to run it on older windows version too...
Thank you for the note on wmic, i've edited my code so that  it try wmic and use get-partition if it fail.
I've actually tried the command in the comment that you suggested before posting, it wasn't working due to the space in `model, serialnumber`.

Comment: Note also that the accepted answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960445/get-hard-disk-serial-number-from-local-disk-in-batch] is not stable as per of the comments below the answer, hence the question that i asked.
Anyway, many thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your suggestions :

For windows > 7, In a **powershell** with the SystemDrive environnement variable, the serial number of the current used os can be found with :

```
get-partition -DriveLetter ($Env:SystemDrive).Replace(':','') | get-disk | % {$_.SerialNumber}
```

For older versions of windows,in **cmd.exe**, `wmic` can be used with :

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk WHERE "IsSystem='TRUE'" get serialnumber
```

In python :

```
import subprocess

def get_serial():
    try:
        cmd = r'wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk WHERE "IsSystem=\'TRUE\'" get serialnumber'.replace(
            "\\'", "'")
        serial = subprocess.check_output(cmd)


    except:
        cmd = "get-partition -DriveLetter ($Env:SystemDrive).Replace(':','') | get-disk | % {$_.SerialNumber}"
        ouput = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True)
        serial = ouput.stdout

    return serial
```

Note that calling a powershell and get-partition is fairly slow...

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the serial number, you could try the following `WMIC.exe` command, on supported systems:

```
WMIC.exe /NameSpace:\\ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage Path MSFT_Disk Where IsSystem=TRUE Get SerialNumber
```

---

Running the `WMIC.exe` command as an argument to `cmd.exe`, on supported systems, and output the same information you have indicated, *(but only the OS drive)*, and returning just th serial number, would look like this:

```bash
cmd.exe /D /Q /C "For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe LogicalDisk Where DeviceID^='%SystemDrive%' Assoc:'List' /AssocClass:'Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition' 2^>NUL') Do If "%G" == "DiskIndex" %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where Index=%H Get SerialNumber"
```

---

Obviously if you are running either of these, presumably via the subprocess module, you would need to do so in a way that correctly handles all of the shown backward slashes, quotes, commas etc.

*I would also always strongly advise that you use fully qualified absolute paths. `WMIC.exe` should always be located on the System drive, under `\Windows\System32\wbem\`, and `cmd.exe` also on the System drive, under `\Windows\System32\`.*

Comment: Sorry i don't see the point for the first one because i just want the serial number, and what is the difference in between Index and Number ?
The second command is just not working for me

Comment: If you didn't want the output shown in your question, you should have made that clear. The second command works flawlessly, I use it myself on all of my client machines, (which have WMIC.exe). If it's not working for you testing directly in cmd.exe, you must have tried to change something. If it's not working for you in python.exe, then you've failed to correctly handle all of the shown backward slashes, quotes, commas etc.

Comment: Indeed my bad ! I was running the commands in a Powershell, it runs without problems in cmd.exe. 'If you didn't want the output shown in your question, you should have made that clear.', I think that the whole point of the two last sentences, sorry if it wasn't clear enough